# How is JFrame.setResizable supposed to be used?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to followed java tutorials and now I am going over `JFrame`.

This is a information inquiry more than help question.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Login {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Creating object of LoginFrame class and setting some of its properties
        LoginFrame frame = new LoginFrame();
        frame.setTitle("LoginForm");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(10, 10, 370, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

This code will cause the frame to be resized to a very small size at the top left corner regardless of the bounds I set.

A simple fix for this is to place `frame.setResizable()` before setting its bounds.

Does anyone know why this happens or am I doing something wrong?

I'm also on Ubuntu 20.04, maybe this matters but I haven't found an answer.

Tutorial shows above code.

The following is the code for `LoginFrame`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

//Creating LoginFrame class
public class LoginFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    //Creating constructor of LoginFrame() class
    LoginFrame(){

    }

    //Overriding actionPerformed() method
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    }
}
```

Like I was saying I was only following a tutorial. This was only the beginning of the tutorial but I had the same issue when starting another very simple frame tutorial.

Comment: It could be an issue with the window already been realised on the screen, this could cause the underlying OS to discard the old window and create a new one ... maybe ... possibly.  You code works on MacOS, but I replaced `LoginFrame` with `JFrame` which might change the results.  As a generally rule, I encourage you to set the frames desired properties before calling `setVisible`

Comment: I suspect MadProgrammer is correct. From the `setBounds` javadoc it reads "The method changes the geometry-related data. Therefore, the native windowing system may ignore such requests, or it may modify the requested data, so that the Window object is placed and sized in a way that corresponds closely to the desktop settings." which tends to imply that future calls that modify the window like `setResizable` could be ignored.

Comment: We have no idea what the LoginFrame class is or does. Actually you should NOT be extending a JFrame. You only extend a class when adding new functionality to the class. Adding components to a frame is not adding functionality. The setResizable() method method is typically invoked AFTER adding components to the frame and BEFORE invoking pack() and setVisible(). In general you should NOT be using setBounds() to set a random size to the frame. The frame should be packed so all components are displayed at their preferred sizes.

Comment: @camickr Like a said I was only following a online tutorial. I'm sorry if I made a mistake.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am wondering if it is a problem with internal memory or something more complicated i wouldn't understand now. Either setting Resizable before Bounds or setting Visible last fixes this issue or bug. Not sure if its my fault or something else.

Comment: *"Like I was saying I was only following a tutorial."* Follow a different tutorial. The way to size a frame is to call `pack()` after components are added & `setResizable(false)` is called (that changes the window chrome & thus size needed). The way to position a frame is to call `setLocationByPlatform(true)` before it is set visible. **Edit:** Oh, I see that @camickr already addressed `pack()` ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I get why you would want to use pack() and setLocationByPlatform(). However, is it logically wrong to set the location and size to my own preference? I wanted to know why my frame gets resized. In the case of the next answer, I copied and pasted the code that he posted and I still get the same issue while his code works fine on his end. Making me believe that I did not do something wrong and that the problem had to do with something internally. So far pack() and setLocationByPlatform() seems preference rather than logical.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me :

```java
import javax.swing.*;

class Scratch extends JFrame {

    public Scratch() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Creating object of LoginFrame class and setting some of its properties
        Scratch frame = new Scratch();
        frame.setTitle("LoginForm");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(10, 10, 370, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Result : I see a big rectangular window - in the shape of a smart phone screen I'd say.

`setResizable(false)` means you cannot resize the frame. I suspect the problem you're trying to identify lies somewhere in the `LoginFrame` class... no code for this was included though so hard to comment furhter.

Comment: This does not work for me. It creates the same issue.

However if I set resizable before setting the bounds it works.

What you described is exactly what I get if I place frame.setResizable before frame.setBounds.

Comment: I did wonder about whether it was an ordering issue but it was fine locally